# Where does user click on progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an audio player and a progress bar. I'm letting users click on the progress bar. When they click on the bar, it advances the audio player. The position where the user clicked on the progress bar is where the audio player should start. Here's my code.
So if the user clicks on the 80% position in the progress bar, the audio player should be 20% of the way from finishing playing the song.

```
  var aud = $('audio')[0];
  $('.progress-bar-wrapper').on('click', (e) => {
     var posX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
     var percentage = parseInt((posX / $(this).width()) * 100);
     aud.currentTime = percentage/100 * aud.duration;
     $('.progress:eq(' + index + ')').css('width', percentage + '%');
  });
```

Unfortunately, this is not precise. When I click on the 80% position in the progress bar, it does not move the audio player to the 80% duration. What should I do?

Comment: Get the window witdh and progress bar width. Normalize and you get the exact values.

Comment: How's that different from what I'm currently doing @MarkusZeller?

Comment: There is no normalization. If you take the window width as 100% you can map exactly the x position to the progressbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran your code with out changing too much, made a few little tweeks but your math seems to work good in my demo.

I change your percentage to `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt` which makes it more accurate.

See comments in code below and fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/v20ndcue/

```js
// window on load
$(window).on('load', function(e) {

  // once audio loaded get the audio object
  let aud = $('audio')[0];

  // on prorgess bar wrapper click
  $(document).on('click', '.progress-bar', function(e) {
  
    // get x position in progress bar
    let posX = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    let progressWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    
    // create percentage from position etc
    let percentage = parseFloat((posX / progressWidth) * 100);
    
    // set the audio current time to progress position
    aud.currentTime = percentage / 100 * aud.duration;
    
    // update the progress bar width
    $('.progress',this).css('width', percentage + '%');

  });

});
```

```css
HTML {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

BODY {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  height: 100%;
}

AUDIO {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

.progress-bar {
  position: relative;
  height: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background: #fff;
}

.progress-bar .progress {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  background: #2e71ff;
}
```

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://dev.joshmoto.wtf/mp3/crane-flock-aproaching.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/0qydrf3t/
```

Added a few more tweeks, but a little rough, to handle multiple audio clips, with a function to handle/return audio item data (globally)...

https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/0qydrf3t/